# Where can I get the language-specific Office 2013 Preview?

Tags: microsoft-office, language, office-2013-preview

I have installed office 2013 preview a month or so ago on my desktop (64 bit installer) in Dutch.

Now I want to install it on my laptop, but the only thing that I can find is an English or a Spanish version! ([here](http://www.microsoft.com/office/preview/en)) I cannot use the same installer as the previous, because my lappy has a 32bit OS.

Comment: Where did you get it from originally (link)?  Where are you trying to get it from now?  If you want to know "why" MS does anything, you'll probably have to ask them... :)

Comment: @techie007 That's a bit of the problem, I don't know anymore! But I will post on the Microsoft Forums and will post back here when they have answered me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013** 60-day evaluation version is available [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/jj192782.aspx) in:

- 32-bit and 64-bit editions
- These languages: Arabic, Chinese (Simplified), Chinese (Traditional), **Dutch**, English, French, German, Hebrew, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese (Brazil), Russian, Spanish